# (Ficheros) El primer método imprime también el segundo

Tags: java

Estoy practicando los ficheros de Java en netbeans y tenía una duda que no logro solucionar:

```
public class Ficheros {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Ficheros m = new Ficheros();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("Prova.txt");
        m.introduir();
        int eleccio = sc.nextInt();
        while (eleccio != 4) {
            if (eleccio == 1) {
                m.fichero(file);
            }
            if (eleccio == 2) {
                m.lectura(file);
            }
            eleccio++;
        }
    }

    public int introduir() {
        System.out.println("Elegir opcion");
        System.out.println("Verificar el fichero");
        System.out.println("Leer el fichero");
        return 0;
    }

    public void fichero(File file) {

        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Existe");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It doesn't");
        }
    }

    public void lectura(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println("");
        while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());

        }
        entrada.close();
    }
}
```

Cuando elijo el `1`, me muestra tanto el resultado del primer método como del segundo, haciendo un efecto cascada. Cosa que no pasa con la segunda.

Alguna solución?

Comment: por favor lee los comentarios que estamos dejando en la respuesta. Tu codigo ademas de confuso tiene errores mas profundos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta es sencilla, lo hace porque al final de tu ciclo estás elevando el valor de eleccio:

```
while (eleccio != 4) {
            if (eleccio == 1) {
                m.fichero(file);
            }
            if (eleccio == 2) {
                m.lectura(file);
            }
            eleccio++;
        }
```

`eleccio++;` hace que suba el valor, si llega en primer lugar como 1, al subir su valor se vuelve 2 y hará que sea óptimo para que entre en tu segunda condición. La manera más sencilla que se me ocurre para solucionarlo, es agregar una bandera para saber si accedió al primer if, tu código quedaría así:

```
boolean bandera=false;    
while (eleccio != 4) {
                if (eleccio == 1) {
                    m.fichero(file);
                    bandera=true;
                }
                if (eleccio == 2 && !bandera) {
                    m.lectura(file);
                }
                eleccio++;
            }
```

Con esto, tu método sabrá si ya se ejecutó el primer if, y evitará entrar al segundo, si ya se ejecutó el primer if.

Comment: Ademas de esto, seria ideal que Unomia explique porque puso sus dos if dentro de un while :/

Comment: me limito a lo que hizo el OP, aunque sí me parece algo extraño :l

Comment: O sea.. poner una bandera adentro de un if para un while que no hace nada.. **suena a una muy mala idea**

Comment: también se me ocurrió meter la bandera en el while, pero pues no sé la razón por la cuál el OP lo hizo así, en fin...

Comment: A veces, en las respuestas, remarcar esa clase de errores tambien es correcto.

Comment: es mas.. si yo escribo 5, entra al while y no sale nunca!!!!!!!

Comment: Son simples pruebas que hago con diferentes funcionalidades, podría haberlo hecho mejor con un switch. Pero es simplemente para probar.